How to handle .htaccess restrictions during plugin installation on Bitnami when .htaccess is disabled?
I have a WordPress plugin that creates folder structures and places an .htaccess file inside these folders to restrict access. This works perfectly in typical WordPress setups, but I’m facing an issue with Bitnami installations because Bitnami disables .htaccess by default for performance and security reasons.
Here is the code I use to create the folders and write the .htaccess file:
// Create folder structure for certificates, assets, and orders
function wworder_create_folder_structure() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $wallet_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/apple_wallet_orders';

    $folders = ['certs', 'assets', 'orders'];
    $htaccess_content = "Order Deny,Allow\nDeny from all";

    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
        $folder_path = $wallet_dir . '/' . $folder;

        // Create the folder if it doesn't exist
        if (!file_exists($folder_path)) {
            wp_mkdir_p($folder_path);
            chmod($folder_path, 0750); // Set folder permissions
        }

        // Always check if the .htaccess file exists, and create if missing
        $htaccess_path = $folder_path . '/.htaccess';
        if (!file_exists($htaccess_path)) {
            file_put_contents($htaccess_path, $htaccess_content);
            chmod($htaccess_path, 0644); // Set .htaccess file permissions
        }
    }
}

// Run only on plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wworder_create_folder_structure');

This works fine on most servers, but in Bitnami, .htaccess files are ignored, and the behavior is managed via httpd-app.conf or bitnami.conf. I want to ensure that the folder access is still restricted automatically when the plugin is installed, even in Bitnami environments.
What is the best way to handle this kind of restriction in Bitnami during the plugin installation process?
I'm looking for a solution that can be automated during plugin installation, without requiring users to manually modify server configuration files.

A script running in the website context being able to manipulate the server configuration, would be bad. Unless Bitnami were to offer some kind of API to perform such updates (so that some form of proper authorization could happen beforehand), I doubt you have much of a choice other than to provide users on that kind of platform with instructions on what they have to update manually.

@C3roe have checked the bitnami documentation regarding the htaccess issue and its recommending to edit the config file during plugin install. But it wasn't clear if the edit has to be made manually or by the plugin it self link

I'm guessing that the user PHP runs under in the website context, will probably not have access to /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/. Plus, the web server needs to be restarted, and that you will be able to issue that sudo command from within that context, is also rather unlikely.

@C3roe Thank you for the advice, in this case I think the ideal way is to store all certificates content in the database instead of uploading the .pem files. But am not sure if that would work with openssl_pkcs7_sign function.
